# C# Printing Rational Number With High Resolution

Tags: c#, decimal-point, rational-numbers

I have the following conundrum. In C#, I want to store a rational and get a string representation of it's decimal notation.

Normally I would just use `float` or `double` to store the number and get the string but I would like a "high resolution" decimal notation. The `double` data type only gives about 16 characters at best in it's string representation. I am looking for the string representation of the decimal notation to contain many more characters, around 30-50 would be ideal. I need the "high resolution" to check for repeating sub-sequences.

The rational number might be simple but I would like the string representation to be very detailed

Example: `1/7` => `0.1428571428571428571428571428`

**My Question:** Is there a C# data structure in the .NET libraries that will store and print rational numbers like I described above?

Comment: [BigDecimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa286442%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Comment: @elyashiv, that looks like a Java class. This is a C# question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Base Class Library's CodePlex site](http://bcl.codeplex.com/) contains a [BigRational type](http://bcl.codeplex.com/releases/view/42782), which provides " an arbitrary-precision rational number type."  This should provide the detail and precision you wish.

Comment: I'm slightly new to C#, I have downloaded the BigRational library and refferenced the `BigRationalLibrary.dll` file in my IDE. I don't know how to include the library with the `using` statement. What is the BigRationalLibrary's namespace?

Comment: The documentation is your friend.

Comment: @awashburn You'd add `using Numerics;`

Comment: I confused `using System.Numerics;` with `using Numerics;`. My frustrations are now gone!

Comment: It also has some known bugs. See the issues on the CodePlex site.

Comment: I just tried this out, and `BigRational` doesn't seem to even provide a method to format the number using decimal notation. In the example in the question, it displays `1/7` as *1/7*, and I couldn't find any way to format it differently.

Comment: It also seems to be available on NuGet: [BigRationalLibrary](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BigRationalLibrary/).

Answer (score 0):

The only existing work I could find with this functionality was [the `Rational` class provided by Ken Johnson](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88980/Rational-Numbers-NET-4-0-Version-Rational-Computin).

Here's an example to achieve what you wanted:

```
[TestMethod]
public void FormatsAsDecimal()
{
    var oneSeventh = new Rational(1, 7);
    var oneSeventhAsDecimal = oneSeventh.ToString(EApproxmationType.DecimalPlaces, 28, true);
    oneSeventhAsDecimal.Should().Be("0.1428571428571428571428571428");
}
```